# Canvas only displays when background is set to an image

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas, styles

Came across the weirdest thing today.

Canvas would only render if the background was set to the image from image.
If background was set to a colour or another image, the canvas will just disappear.

I can't solve it.
Help much appreciated.

Thanks:))

## HTML

```
<section class="banner">
    <canvas id="nCanvasRender"></canvas>
    <article id="cover_banner">
        <h2>Start Network</h2>
        <h1>THE NETWORK <br/>FOR CHANGE</h1>
        <p>Our vision is to connect people in crisis to the best possible solutions </p>
    </article>
</section>
```

## CSS

```
#myCanvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: orange;
}

.banner {
    background: url('http://whois.domaintools.com/images/backgrounds/dark-desert-hills.jpg');
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#cover_banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Your canvas has an id of `nCanvasRender`. Your CSS is styling `#myCanvas`. Is that intended?

Comment: opps yepp changed it to make it easier for yall to read!! for got to change the other one!!

Comment: Could you also provide some javascript? Otherwise, your canvas is just a transparent block element

Comment: ... and please feel free to use this codepen to make it easier for us: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMNjWo

Comment: It works on code pen:( Cant seem to replicate the error on code pen. Guessing problem is due with loading of the javascript generating the canvas.